# JDK 8 Instrumentation API crashes JVM

Tags: redhat-openjdk

I'm using Red Hat OpenJDK.

I've created a demo project to reproduce JVM crash.

https://github.com/ybulatnikov/instrumentation-bug-demo/

I was looking to report this bug on Red Hat website unsuccessfully.

Comment: This seems to be submitted as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220783.

Comment: Yeah, I reported this issue to oracle before. Since there was no any movement and openjdk is handled by red hat now, I decided to reach red hat people :)